# firebase authentication State Persistence

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

so i'm building a simple login/sign up web pages with firebase service and currently i'm using firebase.auth(); and onAuthStateChanged()... to login and then redirect the user to some homepage but the problem is that the session persistence, like i log in successfully in the login page but after redirecting to the homepage i'm signed out so how can i handle the session problem, i'm working on local files on my pc.

this is login page with local address '../login/index.html'

this is my login code:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('signin_button');
var mail;
var password;

function getInputVal(id){
return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
if (user) {
console.log(user);
console.log(user.email);
window.location.href = '../homepage/index.html';
}
else if(!user){
// User is signed out.
console.log('user is signed out');
}
});



btn.addEventListener('click', e => {

mail = getInputVal('email');
password = getInputVal('pass');


firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(mail, 
       password).catch(function(error) {
// Handle Errors here.

var errorCode = error.code;
var errorMessage = error.message;

console.log(errorCode);
console.log(errorMessage);
});

});
```

*sorry for the bad indentation, i'm new to use stack
thanks in advance

Comment: where is the code for `index.html` to listen to the AuthStateChanges?

Comment: do you mean the homepage/index.html ?
if so, it also got the onAuthStateChanged() method to check for any state change
but when i redirect after logging in
the onState... method of the homepage says i'm logged out

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same question.